# Database restore is missing tables

Tags: sql-server

I am using SSMS 2017 and attempting to restore a SQL Server 2016 backup (`.bak`) file to a new database (the data file and log file names in the original backup are different from the new database I am restoring to), so for example, `db1.bak` is being used to create a new database called `db2` through a restore operation.

After the restore completes, all stored procedures and views are present, but none of the tables are there.

These are the steps I've taken in SSMS to perform the restore:

1. Right click the Databases folder
2. Select "Restore Database"
3. Under the General Page:  For "Source" I choose Device and select the `db1.bak` file, and for "Destination" I enter the name of the new database to be created from the backup (`db2`)
4. Under the Files Page I select Relocate all files to folder (both Data and Log folder paths have been pre-populated with the correct names) as have the Logical File Name and the Restore As paths.
5. Under the Options Page I either select nothing or select Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE).

Once the restore completes "successfully" I expand the newly created db2 and click to expand the tables and receive this error message:

[image: Error message]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the script:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [PdsClone] FROM  DISK = N'F:\SQLBackups\PDS_backup_2017_12_12_001015_0199267.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, MOVE N'PDS_Data' TO N'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.PDS\MSSQL\DATA\PdsClone.mdf',  MOVE N'PDS_Log' TO N'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.PDS\MSSQL\DATA\PdsClone_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5   GO
```

**UPDATE**
I had the server group add another disk to that server and moved the SQL backups there, and I was able to successfully complete the restore this morning. I had previously cleaned off most of the backup files, but could it have been a space issue that prevented the tables from showing up in the restore? Every try it indicated success but no tables.  They are there now, and I am thankful for your suggestions and help!

Comment: In the Restore Database dialog, in the upper left corner is a button that will let you script out the restore (based on what you've selected - it's showing you the T-SQL that your GUI selections produced). Script it out and show us that script. Descriptions of a GUI often leave out critical information.

Comment: I've never seen a SQL Server database restore _only_ restore sp's and views and not tables. What does `select * from sys.tables` return?

Comment: To be clear: it is not really possible for a restore to skip tables, or indeed any object or any data, unless the system tables of the database got corrupted in an extremely creative way that somehow went undetected. Restore cannot restore only some tables, or only some views; that is in fact something many people would wish were possible, but for reasons of having one transactionally consistent database, is not. You can safely ignore this possibility in favor of a bug in Management Studio where it fails to correctly query the system tables, or interprets the results incorrectly.

Comment: With strange things like this, recommend going back to troubleshooting basics.  Try it on another machine.  Try upgrading SSMS.  Try restarting SSMS.  Basically, break it down into the smallest pieces until you can repeat the problem.  Had a different issue recently and upgrading SSMS was the fix.  Got there by verifying my co-worker with a different version of SSMS wasn't having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to what happened, but perhaps SSMS was doing something a little buggy as @JeroenMostert suggested.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  Please check the FAQ for what an acceptable answer would look like.

Answer (score 0):

just had a similar problem SSMS2017 backup wont restore tables t SQL2022 when I create the database first, when I delete database and do restore/create db it works OK for anyone with similar problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This isn't really an answer.  Please check the FAQ for what an acceptable answer would look like.